# Escape field name in jq that contains '@' and '-'?

Tags: key, special-characters, jq

Input JSON:

```
{
  "abc": {
    "@def-ghi": "value1",
    "xyz": "value2"
  }
}
```

And I'm trying to get value for field `@def-ghi`.

```
➜ $?=0 ➤ echo '{"abc": {"@def-ghi": "value1", "xyz": "value2"}}' | jq '.abc.xyz'
"value2"
➜ $?=0 ➤ echo '{"abc": {"@def-ghi": "value1", "xyz": "value2"}}' | jq '.abc.@def-ghi'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.abc.@def-ghi
jq: 1 compile error
➜ $?=3 ➤
```

How to escape the field name properly?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to quote the key:

```
$ echo '...' | jq '.abc."@def-ghi"'
"value1"
```

Answer (score 6):

The most robust alternative is to use the basic form:

```
.[KEY]
```

where KEY is a JSON string, including the outer quotation marks.

This form, however, must be pipelined, so you'd have to write:

```
jq '.abc|.["@def-ghi"]'
```

(The `.[_]` form can also be used for arrays, but of course _ would have to be an integer.)

Comment: Can you explain with example? This doesn't work. `jq '.abc.["@def-ghi"]'`

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi - See update.