# Can JQ work with numbers/lines as category?

Tags: bash, jq

Let say I have the following JSON:

```json
{
  "MS-23-AMW": {
    "brand": "audi",
    "model": "A8",
    "displayName": "Audi A8",
    "engine": "4.5L"
  },
  "SJ-08-REW": {
    "brand": "bmw",
    "model": "335i",
    "displayName": "bmw 3 series",
    "engine": "3.5L"
  }
}
```

How could I get the model lets say for `MS-23-AMV` with JQ?

I tried `jq "cars.MS-23-AMW" cars.json` but i get `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected LITERAL, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:`. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use jq when the variable has reserved characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018393/how-to-use-jq-when-the-variable-has-reserved-characters)

Comment: Second duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494389/escape-field-name-in-jq-that-contains-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the array of cars should be defined as an object where each car is a key-value pair, or as an array of objects

something like this

```
{
  "cars": {
    "ms-23-amw": {
      "brand": "audi",
      "model": "a8",
      "displayname": "audi a8",
      "engine": "4.5l"
    },
    "sj-08-rew": {
      "brand": "bmw",
      "model": "335i",
      "displayname": "bmw 3 series",
      "engine": "3.5l"
    }
  }
}
```

and now use the `jq` to get the model for `ms-23-amw`:

```
jq '.cars."ms-23-amw".model' cars.json
```

output

```
"a8"
```

Comment: Yeah, i invented one on the spot and i didn't check, thanks for the solution